# PHP - Dynamic 3 column result table

Tags: php

I have this script which produces a 3 column table of results:

```
$cols = 3;
$row = 0;
$column = 0;
$count = 0;

echo '<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $count++;
   if ($column == 0) {
      echo '<tr>';
   }
   echo "<td>$row['dbField']</td>";
   $column++;
   if ($column >= $cols) {
      $row++;
      echo '</tr>';
      $column = 0;
   }
}
echo '</table>';
```

This works okay, except if there's only 1 result, it only prints one cell. I would like it to finish off the row of 3, so in this case, two cells would be empty.

I have the total number of records stored in a session variable `$_SESSION['r_count']` and thought it would be fairly simple to add the following snippet after the `$column++` part of the above:

```
if ($count == $_SESSION['r_count'] && $column < $cols) {
    echo '<td></td>';
    $column++;
}
```

I thought wrong. Could anyone advice me on how to modify this correctly?

Comment: How many columns does your database query produce? Just one?

Comment: @GarethL: Columns?? Do you mean rows?

Comment: No, I meant columns. I'm not sure I understood what you want; Are you retrieving 1 single column from the database, but putting that result in a table with three columns? (So basically, in your table you have three ROWS of results from the database in each ROW of the HTML table?)

Comment: @GarethL: No, sorry, I'll explain further. I'm returning 9 records per page for a 3x3 table grid. Each of the 9 records have their own table cell with a visible border. If the database only returns 4 records, I get 1 row of 3 cells and a second row of 1 cell, which looks odd. So now I want the next 2 cells to be appended even though they haven't got a database record, so I'll have 6 cells (3x2) but only 4 have contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the number of rows (i.e. `mysql_num_rows()`):

```
for ($i = 0, $n = ceil($nr_of_rows / $cols); $i != $n; ++$i) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($i % $cols == 0) { echo '<tr>'; }
    echo '<td>', $row ? htmlspecialchars($row['dbField']) : '', '</td>';
    if (($i + 1) % $cols == 0) { echo '</tr>'; }
}
```